# Color html tag from url variables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have `url: localhost/x.php?menu=1`
when I open subcategories of this menu url changes to

`url: localhost/x.php?menu=1&submenu=2` open I open again another item it changes to

`url: localhost/x.php?menu=1&submenu=2&cat=3`

I want to color all the selected divs:

```
<div class="table_caption_H col-sm-1">
   <a href="x.php?MainMenuId='.$menu['Id'].'">//menu
 <a href="x.php?MainMenuId='.$menu.'&submenu='.$submenu.'&submenuId='.$submenuId['Id'] .'">//submenu
```

with this JQuery I can color the selected item but when url changes and page refreshes it doesn't save it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.table_caption_H').click(function(e){
    $(this).css("color", "red");
});
</script>
```

Please help and suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Well if the page navigates of course the color does not stick because it is a new page. You would need to set the color on page load.

Comment: please give me an example

Comment: @RandomUser On the loading of the page, how do you know which menu's should be open?  Without those url parameters they would be closed.  What logic is using the url parameters and making the menus open?

Comment: @Taplar I dont,the user selects them,I am thinking of taking them from url

Comment: Since you are building the href in php, you can also at that point check to see if that is indeed the page they are on (by looking at GET/REQUEST variables), and adding a new class that turns it red.

Comment: Doing the jquery click method is more if you are keeping the user on the same page (no new DOM), but loading more content through ajax or into an iframe somewhere else.

Comment: @IncredibleHat an example please

Comment: @RandomUser: Lookup the jQuery reference for the mehtods you use there to set the CSS. It is written there what HTML is changed for that. As your PHP script returns HTML, change it to that what you would love to achieve with the blueprint of the jquery code you have in your question here.

Comment: `echo '<div class="table_caption_H col-sm-1" style="'. ((isset($_GET['MainMenuId']) && $_GET['MainMenuId'] == $menu['Id']) ? 'color:red;' : '' ) .'">'; ... `

Comment: @IncredibleHat this looks more like an javascript function,to color that div where id equals urls id.now I have to translate logic into code

Comment: @hakre can you provide me with a link,IDK what to search for

Comment: What are you talking about? I gave you a pure-php solution to apply the style to the div when the page is built. This is not javascript (which is where your problem is, since the page is being refreshed after js happens).

Comment: You search for the  style HTML attribute (that is: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/style) in the jQuery ereference for the CSS method: http://api.jquery.com/css The wording is a bit different as different words are used for the same nouns, but with a bit of reading about Javascript, CSS and HTML it should be possible to connect the dots.

Comment: @IncredibleHat do you want some points?

Comment: My suggestion is kind of a hacky one, which is why I didn't want to give it as a solid answer. It may solve the current situation and get you rolling, but it's not pretty ;)